# How to find the position of a word in one column with another column in same dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have two columns in a dataframe train:

Subject                     |Keyword

---

the box is beautiful        |box
delivery reached in time    |delivery
they serve well serve       |serve

How to find the position of keyword in the subject ?

Currently, I am using the for loop:

```
for(k in 1:nrow(train)){
l <- unlist(gregexpr(train$keyword[k],train$subject[k],ignore.case = T))  
train$position[k] <- l}
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: `grep(df$keyword, df$Subject)`

Comment: In the last row of the dataframe, `l == c(6, 17)`. Do you want to set `train$position[3]` to both? Then that column will hold lists.

Comment: grep(df$keyword, df$Subject) this only matches.... i want to find the position of the keyword in the subject.

Comment: yes i have an many rows like that...i want the position for all the all the rows on the basis of the subject.

Comment: Try the `str_locate` function in the `stringr` package.  There is a similar function in the `stringi` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop, just use the locate functions in the stringr or stringi package.

```
train <- data.frame(subject = c("the box is beauty", "delivery reached on time", "they serve well"), 
                    keyword = c("box", "delivery", "serve"), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(stringr)
train$position_stringr <- str_locate(train$subject, train$keyword)[,1]
#locate returns a matrix and we are just interested in the start of keyword.

library(stringi)
train$position_stringi <- stri_locate_first(train$subject, regex = train$keyword)[,1]
#locate returns a matrix and we are just interested in the start of keyword.

train
                   subject  keyword position_stringr position_stringi
1        the box is beauty      box                5                5
2 delivery reached on time delivery                1                1
3          they serve well    serve                6                6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below.

```
#data.frame created using the below statements
Subject <- c("the box is beauty","delivery reached on time","they serve well")
Keyword <- c("box","delivery","serve")
train <- data.frame(Subject,Keyword)


#Solution
library(stringr)
for(k in 1:nrow(train))
{
  t1 <- as.character(train$Subject[k])
  t2 <- as.character(train$Keyword[k])
  locate_vector <- str_locate(t1,regex(t2,ignore.case=true))[[1]]
  train$start_position[k] <- locate_vector
  #If end position is also required, the second column from str_locate 
  #function could be used.
```

}

Comment: this works similar to the for loop written by me.I want any other way to get the position of the keyword in the subject .As i have many tons of records and the for loop takes huge amount of time.